# Days in every month with two dates

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working in HRMS. My problem is in vacation, 
If an employee take vacation from `19/3/2014` to `5/4/2014` application calculates that he take 18 days in month instead of 3 days.

I store vacations in `vacation` table

columns :

```
emp_id | vac_type | from | to
```

Now, How can I make query to tell me that he take 13 days in March and 5 days in April?

Comment: Can it be for two months as well ? I mean leave can be from march to may ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question! I was able to find a way to do it, but I did have to use slightly different notation for the dates (see below).

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, @lastDayOfStartMonth INT

SET @startDate = '3/19/2014'
SET @endDate = '4/5/2014'

SELECT @lastDayOfStartMonth =
    1+DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)+1,0)))

SELECT DATENAME(month, @startDate) AS [Month],
    @lastDayOfStartMonth - DATEPART(dd, @startDate) AS [DaysSpent],
    DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
    DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS [DaysSpent]
```

Output:

```
| Month | DaysSpent | Month | DaysSpent |
|-------|-----------|-------|-----------|
| March |        13 | April |         5 |
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/9)

My work here was based on the design from Pinal Dave's post [SQL SERVER – Find Last Day of Any Month – Current Previous Next](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/)

---

#### Handling dates over more than two months

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, @currentDate DATETIME, @currentDay INT
DECLARE @currentMonth INT, @lastDayOfStartMonth INT 
CREATE TABLE #VacationDays ([Month] VARCHAR(10), [DaysSpent] INT)

SET @startDate = '1/19/2014'
SET @endDate = '4/5/2014'
SET @currentMonth = DATEPART(mm, @startDate)
SET @currentDay = DATEPART(dd, @startDate)
SET @currentDate = @startDate

WHILE @currentMonth < DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
BEGIN
    SELECT @lastDayOfStartMonth =
        DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@currentDate)+1,0)))
    PRINT @lastDayOfStartMonth
    INSERT INTO #VacationDays
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @currentDate) AS [Month],
        @lastDayOfStartMonth - @currentDay + 1 AS [DaysSpent]

    SET @currentDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @currentDate)
    SET @currentMonth = @currentMonth + 1
    SET @currentDay = 1
END

IF DATEPART(mm, @startDate) = DATEPART(mm, @endDate)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #VacationDays
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
        DATEPART(dd, @endDate) - DATEPART(dd, @startDate) + 1 AS [DaysSpent]
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #VacationDays
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @endDate) AS [Month],
        DATEPART(dd, @endDate) AS [DaysSpent]
END

SELECT * FROM #VacationDays
DROP TABLE #VacationDays
```

Output:

```
|    Month | DaysSpent |
|----------|-----------|
|  January |        13 |
| February |        28 |
|    March |        31 |
|    April |         5 |
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/46) - It takes about a minute to run. It's much faster running in a local instance of SSMS.

---

#### Here's how it works

For the example below I am using a @startDate value of `05-05-2015`.

The value of `CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` is the date `1900-01-01`, so that means the line `DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)` is essentially asking, *how many months have passed since January 1, 1900?* For this example, that value is `1384`.

`DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)+1,0)` or `DATEADD(mm, 1384+1,0)` is saying, *Add 1385 months to the date value 0 (or 1900-01-01).* This will give us the DATETIME value of the first of the month *after* @startDate's month. For our example, `2015-06-01`.

`DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)+1,0))` or `DATEADD(s,-1,'2015-06-01')` subtracts 1 second from the first of next month, give us the last second of the current month, or `2015-05-31 23:59:59`.

Then we use `DATEPART` to get the day value of that date: `31`.

31 is the last day in May.

Comment: how can i make it work with many from/to dates , example i have employee with id = 1 hes vacation records is from 1/1/2014 to 7/1/2015 then from 11/2/2014 to 16/5/2014 then 10/9/2014 to 7/10/2014 ...... so the result shuld be 6 dayes in jenury and 18 day in feb and 31 day in march and 30 day in april and 16 day in may and 0 day in jun and so ...

Comment: You could pack the query into a function which takes in two dates and spits out the message you would like. Regarding handling more than 2 months, that is possible, but this particular query won't do it. You would need to make a loop that advanced, counting through each month's days. When I get the chance, I will write something up for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this directly in SQL using a SQL query.  But if you have the start and end dates of the vacation in your C# code, then you could calculate the number of days of vacation occurring in each month by doing something like the following.  This got a little more complicated than I had intended, but it's the best I could come up with.  For your example, this code produces the following output:

```
Vacation days in March:         13 days
Vacation days in April:         5 days
```

Code:

```
class Program
{
    class DateRange
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateRange vacation = new DateRange();
        vacation.Start = new DateTime(2014, 3, 19);
        vacation.End = new DateTime(2014, 4, 5);

        // Assuming April 5 represents the last day of vacation, let's
        // add one to it, to show that his vacation actually ends on the
        // following day.
        vacation.End = vacation.End.AddDays(1);

        DateRange currentMonth = new DateRange();
        currentMonth.Start = new DateTime(vacation.Start.Year, vacation.Start.Month, 1);
        currentMonth.End = currentMonth.Start.AddMonths(1);

        while (currentMonth.Start < vacation.End)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vacation days in {0}: \t{1} days",
                currentMonth.Start.ToString("MMMM"),
                IntersectDates(currentMonth, vacation));

            currentMonth.Start = currentMonth.Start.AddMonths(1);
            currentMonth.End = currentMonth.End.AddMonths(1);
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of days represented by the intersection of the two
    // date ranges.
    static int IntersectDates(DateRange dateRange1, DateRange dateRange2)
    {
        DateTime startOfIntersection = MaxDate(dateRange1.Start, dateRange2.Start);
        DateTime endOfIntersection = MinDate(dateRange1.End, dateRange2.End);

        return (startOfIntersection < endOfIntersection) ?
            (int)(endOfIntersection - startOfIntersection).TotalDays :
            0;
    }

    static DateTime MinDate(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        return (d1 < d2) ? d1 : d2;
    }

    static DateTime MaxDate(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        return (d1 > d2) ? d1 : d2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @FromDate date = '2014-03-19', @ToDate date = '2014-05-04'

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        YEAR(@FromDate) * 100 + MONTH(@FromDate) AS Month,
        DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@FromDate) + 1, @FromDate) AS FirstDateOfMonth, 
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@FromDate) + 1, @FromDate))) AS LastDateOfMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FirstDateOfMonth)) * 100 + MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FirstDateOfMonth)) AS Month,
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FirstDateOfMonth), 
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, FirstDateOfMonth)) 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE @ToDate >= LastDateOfMonth
)
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE
        -- Same month 
        WHEN YEAR(@FromDate) * 100 + MONTH(@FromDate) = YEAR(@ToDate) * 100 + MONTH(@ToDate) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1
        -- Get day from vacation start date to last date of month
        WHEN Month = YEAR(@FromDate) * 100 + MONTH(@FromDate) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, LastDateOfMonth) + 1
        -- Get day from first date of month to vacation end date
        WHEN Month = YEAR(@ToDate) * 100 + MONTH(@ToDate) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, FirstDateOfMonth, @ToDate) + 1
        -- Full month day
        ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, FirstDateOfMonth, LastDateOfMonth) + 1
    END AS Day
FROM CTE
```

Result

```
Month       FirstDateOfMonth LastDateOfMonth Day
----------- ---------------- --------------- -----------
201403      2014-03-01       2014-03-31      13
201404      2014-04-01       2014-04-30      30
201405      2014-05-01       2014-05-31      4
```

Answer (score 1):

For applications like these, a dates table can greatly simplify queries at a reasonable cost to performance.  It becomes nothing more than

```
SELECT emp_id, d.month, COUNT(*) as days 
FROM Vacations v 
INNER JOIN dates d on d.theDate BETWEEN v.Start and v.End
GROUP BY emp_id, d.month
```

See [Create Date Dimension Table in SQL Server](http://michaelmorley.name/how-to/create-date-dimension-table-in-sql-server) for an example of how to create a dates table.

This also simplifies complicated queries like the number of business days in a vacation:

```
SELECT emp_id, COUNT(*) as days 
FROM Vacations v 
INNER JOIN dates d on d.theDate BETWEEN v.Start and v.End
WHERE d.IsWeekend = 0
GROUP BY emp_id
```

Or grouping by pay-period or quarter:

```
SELECT emp_id, d.year, d.quarter, COUNT(*) as days 
FROM Vacations v 
INNER JOIN dates d on d.theDate BETWEEN v.Start and v.End
GROUP BY emp_id, d.year, d.quarter
```

Comment: I think this approach is the best one, simple and clean. For OP question, just group by month will do

Answer (score 1):

I create a query that needs a `calendar` that I make it in `WITH` statement, In this calendar you can set your month names and month days -for a leap year-.
The calendar will be flexible for any year that used in vacation table -that automatically generate the correct dates for leap years-, Also support vacations starts from one year to next year.

```
;WITH calendar AS (
SELECT  years.[Year], months.monthId, months.[monthName],
        CASE ISDATE(CONVERT(varchar, years.[Year])+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthId)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthDays)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN months.monthDays
            ELSE months.monthDays-1
        END AS monthDays,
        CONVERT(datetime, (CONVERT(varchar, years.[Year])+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthId)+'-1')) AS startDay,
        CASE ISDATE(CONVERT(varchar, years.[Year])+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthId)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthDays)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, years.[Year])+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthId)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthDays))
            ELSE CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, years.[Year])+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthId)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,months.monthDays-1))
        END AS EndDay
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(vi.[from]) As [Year] FROM vacation vi
     UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(vi.[to]) As [Year] FROM vacation vi
    ) As years
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 As monthId, 31 As monthDays, 'January' As [monthName] UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 29, 'February' UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 31, 'March' UNION ALL
     SELECT 4, 30, 'April' UNION ALL
     SELECT 5, 31, 'May' UNION ALL
     SELECT 6, 30, 'June' UNION ALL
     SELECT 7, 31, 'July' UNION ALL
     SELECT 8, 31, 'August' UNION ALL
     SELECT 9, 30, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 31, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 30, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 31, 'December' ) As months
)
SELECT c.[year], c.monthId, c.[monthName],
    CASE 
        WHEN v.emp_id IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN c.monthId = MONTH(v.[from]) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, v.[from], c.EndDay) + 1
        WHEN c.monthId = MONTH(v.[to]) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, c.startDay, v.[to]) + 1
        WHEN c.monthId BETWEEN MONTH(v.[from]) AND MONTH(v.[to]) THEN c.monthDays
    END As vacationDays,
    CASE 
        WHEN v.emp_id IS NULL THEN c.monthDays
        WHEN c.monthId = MONTH(v.[from]) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, c.startDay, v.[from]) 
        WHEN c.monthId = MONTH(v.[to]) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, v.[to], c.EndDay)
        WHEN c.monthId BETWEEN MONTH(v.[from]) AND MONTH(v.[to]) THEN 0
    END As nonvacationDays,
    c.monthDays

FROM 
    calendar c
    LEFT JOIN
    vacation v ON c.monthId BETWEEN MONTH(v.[from]) AND MONTH(v.[to])
```

The result will be like this:

```
year | monthId | monthName | vacationDays | nonvacationDays | monthDays
-----+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+------------
2014 | 1       | January   | 0            | 31              | 31
2014 | 2       | February  | 0            | 28              | 28
2014 | 3       | March     | 13           | 18              | 31
2014 | 4       | April     | 5            | 25              | 30
2014 | 5       | May       | 0            | 31              | 31
--....
```